# Flask-Socketio:Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503 & WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: flask, heroku, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

So, I am trying to deploy my chat app to Heroku I saw some answers but none of them are with flask-socketio and they are with solutions that you can't do in flask-socketio. I followed the steps in [here](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#gunicorn-web-server). In addition you can there is an error in the logs

```
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811700+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811746+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 461, in fire_timers
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811747+00:00 app[web.1]: timer()
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811751+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/timer.py", line 59, in __call__
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811752+00:00 app[web.1]: cb(*args, **kw)
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811754+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/semaphore.py", line 147, in _do_acquire
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811754+00:00 app[web.1]: waiter.switch()
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811783+00:00 app[web.1]: File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 858, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811811+00:00 app[web.1]: File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 829, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet._Greenlet__report_result
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811814+00:00 app[web.1]: File "src/gevent/_gevent_cgreenlet.pxd", line 45, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.get_my_hub
2020-07-09T14:55:03.811863+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot convert greenlet.greenlet to gevent._gevent_c_greenlet_primitives.SwitchOutGreenletWithLoop
2020-07-09T14:55:03.812531+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NCq5C0_&sid=59a6f168828134cc39e7314cf4639909f" host=chat-py.herokuapp.com request_id=9c21cf77-3a08-44b9-917b-da87c2dad3fc fwd="176.229.186.130" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=202 protocol=http
2020-07-09T14:55:33.809904+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NCq5C13&sid=59a63f16888134cc39e7314cf4639909f" host=chat-py.herokuapp.com request_id=5ca46303-e131-4a64-844a-0070916051dc fwd="176.229.186.130" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2020-07-09T14:55:33.920874+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=59a6f16888234cc39e7314cf4639909f" host=chat-py.herokuapp.com request_id=87ec71b4-c64a-4e3a-bf31-c6fda30eda3f2 fwd="176.229.186.130" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

I can see the site up and running but for some reason there is a problem connecting to the socket-io in the network tab (you can't send messages and it worked in localhost).

network tab
[image: network tab]

> Pipfile:

```
flask = "*"
flask-sqlalchemy = "*"
flask-socketio = "*"
flask-login = "*"
sqlalchemy = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
psycopg2 = "*"
eventlet = "*"
gevent-websocket = "*"
```

> Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 app:app
```

(the server name is app)

> connecting to socketio:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="hidden" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

> start of the frontend code (JS):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var socket = io("http://chat-py.herokuapp.com:" + location.port);
.....
```

> Heroku logs

```
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.8.3
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (570f04)…
remote:        Ignoring cffi: markers 'platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and sys_platform == "win32"' don't match your environment
remote:        You are using pip version 9.0.2, however version 20.1.1 is available.
remote:        You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

> UPDATED network tab:

after using the cors_allowed_origins option configuration I was left with a single error (I am pretty sure that the cause of the error is in the logs):
[image]

Comment: Look in the browser's network tab to see what the communication between client and server looks like.

Comment: @Miguel Yeah I forgot about it. Updated the question

Comment: The 400 error could be a cross-origin issue if you haven't done anything to prevent it. This is because the Flask app does not know the domain on which Heroku put it up. See the `cors_allowed_origins` option to configure your domain as an allowed origin. The 503 errors I'm not sure, those do not come from the application.

Comment: @Miguel Alright I am on it. And why is the websocket is closed before the connection is established happening? Is it because of the 400/503 error?

Comment: Right, the errors are happening in the connection request(s) so you never get to the end of the connection attempt.

Comment: @Miguel Yeah, it fixed the error 400 by doing `socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins=['http://chat-py.herokuapp.com'])`. I still have the 503 though.. I think the cause of the error is because of the log error but I didn't find a good solution for it.

Comment: Get the logs from your Heroku app to see if there's anything interesting there.

Comment: @Miguel Not really a regular success message(because the site is up but just the socketio doesn't work well). the only this is that I need to upgrade from python 3.8.2 to 3.8.3 but I really don't think it matters

Comment: @Miguel So what do you suggest?

Comment: As I said, recheck the logs now that you fixed the 400s.

Comment: @Miguel I did (updated the question). But there is nothing special I just need to upgrade pip and python from 3.8.2 to 3.8.3 I really don't think that this is the cause of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I am not sure what fixed it but I'll tell you what I did in the push that worked, I reinstalled `gunicorn`(actually did it multiple times) and upgraded python from 3.8.2 to 3.8.3(by changing the runtime.txt from `python-3.8.2` to `python-3.8.3`). After I pushed it to heroku and entered into the site it just worked.